# Вывести значения ID и Name без повторения Name

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть таблица:

```
+----------------+
|ID  |Name       |
+----------------+
|1000|WorkingJob1|
|1001|WorkingJob1|
|1002|WorkingJob1|
|1003|SomeJob1   |
|1004|SomeNewJob1|
|1005|SomeNewJob1|
|1006|AnotherJob1|
|1007|AnotherJob2|
+----------------+
```

Нужно написать запрос, который вернет ID и Name так, чтобы Name не повторялся.

Результат:

```
 +----------------+
 |ID  |Name       |
 +----------------+
 |1000|WorkingJob1| 
 |1003|SomeJob1   |
 |1004|SomeNewJob1|
 |1006|AnotherJob1|
 |1007|AnotherJob2|
 +----------------+
```

Как вивести уникальные имена - понятно, с помощью DISTINCT. Но как добавить еще ID - не понятно.

Comment: `select min(ID), Name from table_name group by Name;`

Comment: в данном случае не с помощью distinct, а с помощью `group by name`. а для id при этом надо выбрать правильную агрегатную функцию, судя по примеру вы хотите минимальный ID, значит надо применить min(id)

Comment: мне кажется вызов min для сортировки лишний (оrder_by) будет самый раз, а для ограничения дубликатов конечно лучше group_by

Comment: @Jenyokcoder причем тут сортировка ? если требуется минимальное значение, то min() это единственный вариант. И большинство СУБД просто выдадут ошибку, если к полю ID, не участвующем в group by, не будет применена агрегатная функция. А те СУБД, которые позволяют такие вольности _не гарантируют_ какой именно ID окажется в результате и запрос можно будет трактовать как "выдающий один, случайный id из списка"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Правильный ответ `select min(ID), Name from table_name group by Name;`

Спасибо MaxU!

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH MyTable (id,name,rn)
AS
(
SELECT id,name,ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by name order by name)rn from #MyTable
)

SELECT id,name FROM MyTable WHERE rn=1
order by id
```

Вместо #MyTable поставьте имя своей таблицы

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MIN(ID), MAX(ID), Name
FROM dbo.Table1
GROUP BY Name
```